# Twisted Producer was never unregistered

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I am writing a custom SSL proxy with Twisted. I keep running in to an issue that happens every so often and I cant figure out what the problem is.

When I try to connect the client transport to the server's transport through the registerProducer function exactly as twisted.protocols.portforward functions I keep getting this error.

```
      File "/opt/Memory/Mobile/Proxy/forwarder.py", line 40, in connectionMade
        self.peer.transport.registerProducer(self.transport, True)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 602, in registerProducer
        self.transport.registerProducer(producer, True)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", line 233, in registerProducer
        FileDescriptor.registerProducer(self, producer, streaming)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 104, in registerProducer
        raise RuntimeError(
    builtins.RuntimeError: Cannot register producer <twisted.protocols.tls._ProducerMembrane object at 0x7fb5799f0910>, because producer <twisted.protocols.tls._ProducerMembrane object at 0x7fb579b474c0> was never unregistered.
```

Here are my Inherited Classes from twisted?

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import ssl
from twisted.protocols import portforward

from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.python import log
import sys

##SSLProxy base class that will be inherited
class SSLProxy(protocol.Protocol):
    noisy = True
    peer = None

    def setPeer(self, peer):
        #log.msg("SSLProxy.setPeer")
        self.peer = peer

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        #log.msg("SSLProxy.connectionLost")
        if self.peer is not None:
            self.peer.transport.loseConnection()
            self.peer = None
        elif self.noisy:
            log.msg("Unable to connect to peer: {}".format(reason))

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        #log.msg("SSLProxy.dataReceived")
        if self.peer is not None:
            self.peer.transport.write(data)

##Foward data from Proxy to => Remote Server
class SSLProxyClient(SSLProxy):
    def connectionMade(self):
        #log.msg("SSLProxyClient.connectionMade")
        self.peer.setPeer(self)

        self.transport.registerProducer(self.peer.transport, True)
        self.peer.transport.registerProducer(self.transport, True)

        # We're connected, everybody can read to their hearts content.
        self.peer.transport.resumeProducing()



class SSLProxyClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = SSLProxyClient

    def setServer(self, server):
        #log.msg("SSLProxyClientFactory.setServer")
        self.server = server

    def buildProtocol(self, *args, **kw):
        #log.msg("SSLProxyClientFactory.buildProtocol")
        prot = protocol.ClientFactory.buildProtocol(self, *args, **kw)
        prot.setPeer(self.server)
        return prot

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        #log.msg("SSLProxyClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed")
        self.server.transport.loseConnection()


class SSLProxyServer(SSLProxy):
    clientProtocolFactory = SSLProxyClientFactory
    reactor = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        log.msg("SSLProxyServer.connectionMade")

        #Get Current SSL Context
        ssl_context = self.transport._tlsConnection.get_context()

        #Hack to get SNI to do two functions in diffrent classes
        ssl_context._finishSNI = self.SNICallback

    def SNICallback(self, connection):
        #log.msg("SSLProxyServer.SNICallback: {}".format(connection))
        #print(connection.get_context().new_host)

        self.transport.pauseProducing()
        #self.transport.transport.pauseProducing()
        #print(dir())

        self.dst_host, self.dst_port = connection.get_context().new_host

        #Setup Clients
        self.client = self.clientProtocolFactory()
        self.client.setServer(self)

        #Start stuff
        log.msg('Redirecting to {}:{}'.format(self.dst_host, self.dst_port))

        if self.reactor is None:
            self.reactor = reactor

        log.msg("Making Connection to Dest Server: {}:{}".format(self.dst_host, self.dst_port))
        self.reactor.connectSSL(self.dst_host, self.dst_port, self.client, ssl.ClientContextFactory())

        #self.transport.resumeProducing()

    #Client -> Proxy
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        log.msg("SSLProxyServer.dataReceived: {}".format(data))

        #Call Inherited Function
        super().dataReceived(data)

class SSLProxyFactory(protocol.Factory):
    """Factory for port forwarder."""
    protocol = SSLProxyServer

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #log.msg("SSLProxyFactory.__init__")

def sslToSSL(localport, remotehost, remoteport, serverContextFactory):
    log.msg("SSL on localhost:{} forwarding to SSL {}:{}".format(localport, remotehost, remoteport))
    return reactor.listenSSL(localport, SSLProxyFactory(), serverContextFactory)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you just unregister the current Producer you can register the new one.

```py
##Foward data from Proxy to => Remote Server
class SSLProxyClient(SSLProxy):
    def connectionMade(self):
        #log.msg("SSLProxyClient.connectionMade")
        self.peer.setPeer(self)

        self.transport.registerProducer(self.peer.transport, True)
        self.peer.transport.unregisterProducer()
        self.peer.transport.registerProducer(self.transport, True)

        # We're connected, everybody can read to their hearts content.
        self.peer.transport.resumeProducing()
```